# How to fix incorrect coordinate data for the mouse's position

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I am running Quantum GIS 1.8.0 on a 64-bit Windows platform. I've imported a data set that plots correctly when overlaid with a Google Satellite map, so I know that the layer/project CRS is okay (since my points are being projected correctly). The issue is that when I hover my cursor over any point on the map, the reported coordinates are entirely different from the coordinates used for plotting the points. How do I fix this or where can I get information on how to resolve this? I've checked the QGIS bug repository, searched this forum, and reviewed the User Guide.

**example**

plotted point: 
-76.83617103
39.21012998

map coordinates at mouse cursor position (same point as above):
-8553363.45
4751815.77

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The coordinates reported on the bottom of the QGIS window are reported in the project CRS. That would be Web Mercator if you have OpenLayers loaded.

I guess you are expecting WGS84 (GPS) coordinates? You can use the coordinate capture plugin to get WGS84 coordinates independent of the project CRS.

Comment: Thanks! The coordinate capture plugin works perfectly for the point features I'm adding!

Comment: Here is info [how the plugin can be enabled](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/50486/4630). It is not to be fetched and installed, as I thought at first!