# How to turn the QGIS "Coordinate capture" plugin on?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, coordinates

I have enabled the Coordinate Capture Plugin via the Plugins menu. But I cannot seem to *"turn on"* or activate the Plugin and get it running. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Coordinate Capture plugin is activated, you should see the following dock window:

[image]

If you cannot see it, go to View - Panels and select Coordinate Capture.

If you cannot find this entry there, the plugin is not enabled in Plugin Manager (Plugins - Manage Plugins).

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out next time I'm on that computer.

Comment: Once you do this - the top box shows coordinates from a CRS of your choice (button at left to choose). The middle box shows coordinates in the project CRS. The bottom button toggles a continuous update of coordinates (as opposed to them only updating after a mouse click). You need to click 'start capture' to change the mouse function from whatever it was previously set to do. The 'copy to clipboard' button copies both sets of coordinates to the clipboard. (This all might be obvious,  but I personally couldn't find it written down clearly anywhere and struggled at first).

Comment: you should first click on "Copy to Clipboard" to see the coordinates.