# Coordinate Capture plugin missing

Tags: coordinates, plugins

I always had the Coordinate Capture plugin working well, but now it disappeared. I followed the instructions method and others but with no success to get it back to life. I don't have the Coordinate Capture option in Panels to activate, which seems one of the solutions. I upgraded to the latest QGIS stable version 3.22.5 and the problem persists.

How can I enable this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running 3.24.1. These instructions for 3.10 work for me: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_coordinate_capture.html#coordinate-capture-plugin

1. Install the plugin (Plugin Manager)
2. Select Vector -> Coordinate Capture.

The panel appears.

This is also discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50486/how-to-turn-the-qgis-coordinate-capture-plugin-on). If you don't see Coordinate Capture in View -> Panels, check in the plugin manager that you have installed the plugin.

Comment: "These instructions for 3.10 work for me: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_coordinate_capture.html#coordinate-capture-plugin"  This worked for me too, altough I can´t have the shortcut button as I used to have. The second solution was one that I tried and didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From QGIS 3.16 and on, it's possible to copy coordinates directly from maps.

According to SrNetoChan on the issue [5797](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/5797)

> The Coordinates capture plugin / panel as been removed in QGIS 3.14. The reason for that is that the functionality has been added as a map tool. You right-click the map canvas to get several copy coordinate options.